# No getting scopes from RegisteredClient in OAuth2ClientCredentialsAuthenticationProvider in spring-security-oauth2-authorization-server since v0.4.0

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-authorization-server

After updating the spring-security-oauth2-authorization-server from v0.2 to v1.1 while updating Spring Boot I faced that no scopes received by authentification method oauth2/token.

I noticed that inside OAuth2ClientCredentialsAuthenticationProvider authenticate(Authentication authentication) there are some changes with scopes functionality, and we can't take it from registeredClient entity no longer.
[v0.3.1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mybkw.png)
[v1.1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nYnER.png)

I still need to take scopes from table in DB, not sending them by oauth2/token request.
Found any documentation about this change.
Why it was changed and how can I fix it?

I tried to make custom AuthenticationProvider and fix change it, but had some difficulties with autowiring.
private final OAuth2AuthorizationService authorizationService;
private final OAuth2TokenGenerator<? extends OAuth2Token> tokenGenerator;

Comment: Does your client request scopes? Have a look at this [issue](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-authorization-server/issues/780) and this [pull request](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-authorization-server/pull/738).

Comment: Hi, @AlexR, thank you for this precious information! No, my client does not request scopes, and he didn't before.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I face the exact same issue. A simple client-credential auth flow.
The client doesn't send 'scope' in the request to the token endpoint because this is optional and I expect the server will provide it based on the registered client's scope.

I've been debugging the code of OAuth2ClientCredentialsAuthenticationProvider.java to see why there is no 'scope' popluated in the claims.
The code doesn't pull the client's scope at all but just valiate and set the scope  if the client has provided in the request. But not considering the case when it's not provided:

```
if (!CollectionUtils.isEmpty(clientCredentialsAuthentication.getScopes())) {
            for (String requestedScope : clientCredentialsAuthentication.getScopes()) {
                if (!registeredClient.getScopes().contains(requestedScope)) {
                    throw new OAuth2AuthenticationException(OAuth2ErrorCodes.INVALID_SCOPE);
                }
            }
            authorizedScopes = new LinkedHashSet<>(clientCredentialsAuthentication.getScopes());
        }
```

Obviously this is a bug to me.
Wondering how to get around of this problem by customizing the provider.